# Send JSON object and string parameters simultaneously

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to post with jquery JSON object and a string parameter to MVC3 controller method ?

This is my function in the controller :

```
public void myFunction(List<myObject> obj, string myStringparameter)
```

And my javascript function (without string parameter) :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../MyController/myFunction,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ obj: tabJsonObject})
}).success(function (data) {

    //TODO

})
.error(function (response, status, xhr) {
    //TODO
});
```

Without string parameter, it works correctly but I don't know how add this string parameter.

I can't add directly in the url because the URL is too long and I think that add this string in JSON array is bad.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is possible, post json in request body and the string parameter as url parameter, for example, path parameter or query parameter.

Comment: In fact I found the solution by adding only string parameter in url :

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with `data: JSON.stringify({ obj: tabJsonObject, myStringparameter: somestring})` ? If 'myFunction' server side is waiting for a list and a string it should be ok.

Comment: @user1069516 that's what Im talking

Answer (score 1):

In fact I found the solution by adding only string parameter in url :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../MyController/myFunction?myStringparameter=" + myString,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ obj: tabJsonObject})
```